# How to update django variable inside javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Like we can access a variable in the JS part like `"{{vaiable_name}}"`. How can we update the value of `variable_name` inside the javascript?

Let's say code will look like this,

```
{% if variable_name %}
 <p> Condition is true </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: A part of doing some ajax or a form for that ! I don't think to another possible way to do it. If we suppose that the modification must be saved in the database.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to inject a small Javascript through the Django template engine, with {{variable}} substitution.

My own base.html contains

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(  function() {
    {% block onready_js %}{% endblock onready_js %}   
  }); 
</script>
```

and then in any template extending base.html where I want to pass variable values, I can simply code

```
 {% block onready_js %}
      /* some JS with Django substitutions */
      var foo = "{{foo}}";
      ...
 {% endblock %}
```

The one thing you have to remember is that your JS must not contain consecutive open- or close-braces without a space between them!

(If the block is not defined, then the base.html defines a null function to be executed when the document is ready)

Comment: I am not getting this completely, Let's say after clicking a button, I want to change the value of the variable. What should I do?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood question. I though you wanted an easy way to get a Django value out into a JavaScript. HTTP is stateless. There's no way to "change a Django variable" from the client, other than by submitting a POST or similar request. If you don't want a full form submission / validation/ redirection, you can use AJAX in the client script and a handler for the AJAX POST in the Django server.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a span tag with an id and then target the id within javascript

```
<span id='django_variable_id'>{{variable_name}}</span>

<script>
function update_django_variable(new_var){
    /* get the span element */
    var span = document.getElementById('django_variable_id');
    /* set new var here */
    span.innerText = new_var;
}
</script>
```

or will also work as long as there are no other variables with this name

```
<span id='var_{{variable_name}}'>{{variable_name}}</span>

<script>
function update_django_variable(new_var){
    /* get the span element */
    var span = document.getElementById('var_{{variable_name}}');
    /* set new var here */
    span.innerText = new_var;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Let's say, We want to check the if-else condition with the variable.

Comment: I would suggest doing all of that in javascript